# How to redisplay a picture link that I newly add it in an input?

Tags: jquery, ajax, href

I have a form to save data in a database with an ajax query

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "{{ path('element_content_save', {'id': '__ID__'})}}".replace('__ID__', elementId),
    data: postData,
    beforeSend: function() {
        NProgress.start();
    }
}).done(function(r) {
    $('#web-elements').show();
    $('#content-editor').hide();

    if(isCustom){
        if(typeof(elementIdentifier) != 'undefined'){
            var html = $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.getHtmlElement(elementIdentifier).html;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "{{ path('element_save_configurable',{'id':'__ID__'}) }}".replace('__ID__', elementIdentifier),
                data: {html: html},
                beforeSend: function () {
                    NProgress.start();
                }
            }).done(function (r) {
                $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.refreshElementByContentId(elementId);
                NProgress.done();
            });
        } else {
            $('#frame')[0].contentWindow.refreshElementByContentId(elementId);
        }
    }
    NProgress.done();
});
```

In this form I have an input with `id='image-link-input'`, it is a link to a picture. When I hit save all goes right, If I want to re-edit that link that I put it in the first place I want it to appear so I could know what I already put in it.

Comment: You should probably put some screenshot and also your form HTML so that we get to know a bit more detail and are able to suggest a better answer

Comment: Hi shariqkhan thanks for replying,I will give more details , when I save the link or the picture, in the server the href value remind blank,but I want to have an immediate change of the href value and store it in the web first even befoe the database .is that possible ?

Comment: Can you post the url of the page where this code is in place? If you are doing it on local server, then put the screenshot of the form. Also a bit more code-both of the HTML form and the complete function containing the AJAX call

Comment: Also I did not get what you mean by "I want to have an immediate change of the href value and store it in the web".

Where do you want to see the change of the href? And what is meant by :store it in web" ?

Comment: I don't know how to insert screenshot, but i will explain,i mean by change the href :change its value from href=" " to href="mylink.com" for example this must be immediate in the browser (when i hit save i must have the new value) without retreiving it from the database (which takes more time to appear)

Comment: Send a screenshot like this: http://prnt.sc/ccvq5u
You can use prnt.sc to upload the screenshot and give a link here.

Comment: here is the screenshot I hope this is helpfull :http://prnt.sc/ccwew8

Comment: Okay, that screenshot helped. Let me see if I understand it correctly. User enters the url of an image in the field titled "Liens vers URL" and presses the "Save" button. As soon as he/she presses the "Save" button, you want  the image to be displayed in the field titled "Image" and also get saved into the database. 

The database part is working; you only need the first part to work i.e to get the image displayed in the "Image" field on presseing the "Save" button.

Is that correct?

Comment: A part of it is correct ,the user add an image but in field titled "Liens vers URL" it is the link where we will be directed if if we click on that image (it is a targeted image with href attribut)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, from what I understand, your use case is like this:
 1. User uploads an image in the field titled "Image"
 2. User enters a url in the input box titled "Liens vers URL"
 3. User clicks on "Save" and then the link gets associated with the image, so that when someone clicks on the image he/she will get redirected to the link saved in the field titled "Liens vers URL". 
 4. This gets saved in the database. But since this takes a bit time because of being AJAX call, you want the image to be instantly linked to the url, on the form.

If all this is correct, then see code snippet below.

What I am doing here is I am catching the imagePath from the textbox and then setting it as an anchor link.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('#saveImage').click(function() {
  var imgPath = jQuery('#image-link-input').val();
  var imgDest = jQuery('#image-destination').val();
  

  var imgElement = '<a href="' + imgDest + '">' + '<img src="' + imgPath + '">' + '</a>';

  jQuery('#imageholder').html(imgElement);
  jQuery('#imageControls').append('<p class="success">Success!!. Now Click on the image to be redirected to the link</p>');
 });
});
```

```css
#imageholder {
  background:url(http://www.gavaghan.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/placeholder-300x200.png);
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:30px;
}
.success {
  margin-top:20px;
  border:2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="imageholder">
    <img id="blah" src="http://www.gavaghan.ca/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/placeholder-300x200.png" alt="your image" />
</div>


<div id="imageControls">
 <p>
  Enter the path of an image in the text box below. <em> eg. http://free4kwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/nature/Colorful-UHD-4K-Mountains-Wallpaper-300x200.jpg </em>
 </p>
 <input type="text" id="image-link-input"/>
 <p>
  Enter the url where the image should redirect.  <em> eg. www.rediff.com</em>
 </p>
 <input type="text" id="image-destination"/>
 <button id="saveImage">Save</button>
</div>
```